# Sumifs function where I want to sum a range not just a single row or column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am stuck.

I am entering timesheet date into an excel sheet:
Column A - Resource Name
Column B - Project Phase
Column C - Resource Team...
Column D to AAA is a date
Therefore a single resource could have multiple records as they work across multiple Project Phases and Resource terams.

I want to create a table that summarises total timesheet days by:
Prolect Phase and Resource Group on the vertical axis and Month on the horizontal axis.

When I specify the sum range as $D$3:$AAA$100 I get a #value error, as it only wants a single row to be specified. I am using criteria to specify Project Phase and Resource Group and Month (as determined from the date.

Whilst it may be better to use a pivot table I also need to bring in budget data  from another worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SUMIF() can be applied only to single row or column, your evaluation must be carried out in 2 steps.
First use SUMIF() on rows and also concatenate the condition values for each summation in an adjacent cell.  This concatenated string will serve as a key in next step.
Next apply SUMIF() to the column that contains row sums, using the "key" from previous step as the condition.

Comment: HI gm2,  is that "great mind"Not sure what you mean by "

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "concaytenated string"

Comment: @David Barbera please post some example days in your question, that will help to give you more tailored help.